# Minimize $f(x)=\lambda|x|+1/2(x-a)^2$

Tags: optimization

I have so far:

$x-a+\lambda = 0,x>0$

$x-a-\lambda = 0,x<0$

Is there an explicit solution w.r.t. $a$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: i think this is A.M-G.M application question, to minimize the G.M you need to equate both terms and find $x$

Comment: Split the problem into two cases, $\lambda \ge 0$ and $\lambda <0 $. It might help to note that $|x| = \max(x,-x)$.

Comment: I have the choice between $x=a-\lambda$ or $x=a+\lambda$ (depending on $sign(x)$).When plugged into  $f(x)$, they both yield $1/2*\lambda^2$ at the end. So it really depends on the first term, right? The first $|x|$ is minimal for $min(a-\lambda,a+\lambda)$. Is this my x? $min(a-\lambda,a+\lambda)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts...

Given 
$$\min_x f(x) = \lambda |x| + \frac{1}{2}(x-a)^2$$
we find $$f^{\prime}(x) = \lambda \frac{x}{|x|} + (x-a) \\ f^{\prime\prime}(x) = 1.$$

Now the minimum will occur either when $f^{\prime}(x)= 0$ or when $x$ is at an endpoint (i.e., unbounded). Assuming $x \neq 0$, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x\lambda - a|x| + x|x|}{|x|} &= 0 \\
x\lambda - a|x| + x|x| &= 0 \\
x\lambda + x|x| &= a|x| \\
\frac{x\lambda + x|x|}{a} &= |x| \\
\end{align}
$$
Now we have two cases:
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x &= \frac{x\lambda + x|x|}{a} \\
x &= -\frac{x\lambda + x|x|)}{a}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
These cases end up giving the same result, so following the first case, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{ax + x\lambda + x|x|}{a} &= 0 \\
x(a-\lambda - |x|) &= 0 \\
a - \lambda - |x| &= 0 \quad \text{ (assuming } x\neq 0 \text{ again)} \\
|x| = a - \lambda
&\implies
\begin{cases}
x = a - \lambda \\
x = -(a - \lambda)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ok cool. So $x$ is determined by $min(a-\lambda,a+\lambda)$. This seems to be what I wrote in the above comment. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, if you draw it with a fixed positive $\lambda$, a on the x-axis and x on the y-axis you get soft thresholding! https://www.google.ch/search?q=soft+thresholding&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4kqPLi6jXAhXFSRoKHUt3CMYQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=612#imgrc=FVrk0OP7FKMH0M:

Comment: Cool! I didn't think of it this way, but now that you mention it, the structure reminds me of a [regularized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) problem! Also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularized_least_squares!)